# adding the id to the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so i am creating an hash and i need to add the id to the hash..here is my code

```
h = Hash.new {|h1, k1| h1[k1] = Hash.new{|h2, k2| h2[k2] = []}}
@result, today = [ h, h.dup], Date.today

Request.find_all_by_artist("Metallica", :select => "DISTINCT venue, showdate, LOWER(song) AS song, id").each do |req|
 # need to insert the req.id in the hash somewhere 
  idx = req.showdate < today ? 0 : 1
  @result[idx][req.venue][req.showdate] << req.song.titlecase
end
```

any suggestions on how to do this

here is my loop in the view

```
<% @result.each do |venue, date| %>

<li>
    <a href="#"><%= venue %></a>
            <% date.each do |key, song| %>
            <%= key %>
            <ul class="acitem">
                <% puts key.inspect %>
                <% puts song.inspect %>

                    <% songs.each do |each_song, count| %>
                    <li><%= each_song %> <%= each_song %></li>
                <% end %><% end %>
    </ul>
</li>
<% end %>
```

i need to have the id of every request as well....any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you push in the whole record and not just the title you will have access to this information when iterating over the song listing.

```
@result[idx][req.venue][req.showdate] << req
```

You can then use this as you would normally in your view:

```
<% songs_requests.each do |song_request, count| %>
  <li id="song_<%= song_request.id %>"><%= song_request.song.titlecase %></li>
<% end %>
```

The view you've pasted and the structure defined in the controller don't seem to match up completely so I've tried to paint the general picture here.